# Import csv Python with Spyder

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to import a csv file into Python but it doesn't seem to work unless I use the Import Data icon.

I've never used Python before so apologies is I am doing something obviously wrong.  I use R and I am trying to replicate the same tasks I do in R in Python.

Here is some sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os as os

Main_Path = "C:/Users/fan0ia/Documents/Python_Files"
Area = "Pricing"
Project = "Elasticity"
Path = os.path.join(R_Files, Business_Area, Project)
os.chdir(Path)

#Read in the data
Seasons = pd.read_csv("seasons.csv")
Dep_Sec_Key = pd.read_csv("DepSecKey.csv")
```

These files import without any issues but when I execute the following:

```
UOM = pd.read_csv("FINAL_UOM.csv")
```

Nothing shows in the variable explorer panel and I get this in the IPython console:

```
In [3]: UOM = pd.read_csv("FINAL_UOM.csv")
```

If I use the Import Data icon and use the wizard selecting DataFrame on the preview tab it works fine.
The same file imports into R with the same kind of command so I don't know what I am doing wrong?  Is there any way to see what code was generated by the wizard so I can compare it to mine?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the data had imported, it just wasn't showing in the variable explorer